# .htaccess rewrite rule ignoring string, multiple GET variables in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make .htaccess rewrite rule to map 4 different get variables and exclude one string. String is unchangeable ie. always will remain same.

Current url is:

```
/car.php?make=bmw&model=z4&year=2006&color=black_metallic
```

It should be like this:

```
car/bmw-z4-2006-black_metallic-for-sale
```

This is I've done so far

```
RewriteRule ^car/^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&color=$4
```

Now I need to ignore string **-for-sale** at the end of the pretty url.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 RewriteRule ^car/([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)/?$ car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&color=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter is hyphen not forward slash hence your `RewriteRule` should also handle that accordingly:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^car/^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+) car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&color=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.